# [MASM]Another 'cannot use 16-bit register with a 32-bit address' error

Tags: assembly, masm

I'm learning assembly language with MASM assembler and I get stuck when I tried to assemble a simple file using this command :`ml /c test.asm`
and the `test.asm` file looks like :

```
.386
.model flat
.code
MOV BP,WORD PTR[BP+4]
END
```

then the problem comes:

> Microsoft (R) Macro Assembler Version 6.14.8444
>
> Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp 1981-1997.  All rights reserved.
>
> Assembling: test.asm
>
> test.asm(4) : error A2155: cannot use 16-bit register with a 32-bit address

the question is ,

32-bit address?I didn't tell the assembler to use a 32-bit address.

and How can I get my code passed?

Comment: Yes, you did. That's what flat model means.

Comment: okay....I modified my code and changed model to small `.MODEL SMALL` and it seems ml let my code passed .

Answer (score 4):

I've done some researches and here is what I've learned

> `.MODEL` directive
>
> - enables use of simplified segments
> - controls the name of the code segment
> - controls the default distance for procedures.
>
> the syntax is :`.MODEL memorymodel, options-optional`
>
> and memorymodel can be `TINY, SMALL, COMPACT, MEDIUM, LARGE, HUGE,or FLAT`
>
> Flat model is similar to tiny model in that all code and data go in a
>   single 32-bit -addressable block of memory.
>
> To write a flat model program, specify the .386 or .486 directive
>   before.

so the directive `.386`is optional if I don't want to use flat model (look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14296455/cant-push-value-to-stack-why))

here are some references

[1  .MODEL](http://www.ousob.com/ng/masm/ng564f9.php)

[2  Logical Segments and Memory Model Directives](http://www.c-jump.com/CIS77/ASM/Directives/lecture.html)