# 'cannot use 16-bit register with a 32-bit address' error

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, x86-16

how am I suppose to do to fix the error message 
'cannot use 16-bit register with a 32-bit address'?

I've typed this at the front of my code, but it still can't run, and there's a warning says 'multiple. MODEL directives found  MODEL ignored'

I've typed this at the front of my code

```
.model large
.data

    loon_pos dw 3860d
    loon_status db 0d

.code
         render_loon:           
        mov cl, ' '         ;draw loon
        mov ch, 1111b       ;hide old loon

        mov bx, loon_pos
        mov es:[bx], cx
```

the assembler points to this line

```
mov es:[bx], cx
```

and shows

```
cannot use 16-bit register with a 32-bit address
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [\[MASM\]Another 'cannot use 16-bit register with a 32-bit address' error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27097644/masmanother-cannot-use-16-bit-register-with-a-32-bit-address-error)

Comment: I've looked that page before but it still doesn't work

Comment: It that really your entire code?  There's no `.386` anywhere?  Did you use a command-line option that implies a model?  Or does the `large` model imply 32-bit addressing in MASM?  The related question seems to imply that only FLAT implies 32-bit addressing.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this error description with this snippet. So it's not a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: What do you type to assemble this code?

Comment: By any chance are you using irvine32?